# Building a Swing class as a team

Tags: java, swing

I'm working on a project with a team of developers.  We have a very junior developer who can create good mockups of UI but that's about it.  I'd like to keep a simple mockup .java file for the junior developer to create the skeleton of the UI and have another .java file for adding listeners and other logic.  Then, there won't be any collisions in subversion when we check-in our code.

I tried just creating a mockup class and extending or wrapping it but all of the swing components are private and I can't call into them.  What else could I do?

Comment: What difference does that make in the design?  None that I can see.

Comment: Why can't you make the fields that hold the Swing components `protected` instead of `private`?

Comment: Why can't the junior developer work on a branch?

Comment: How does a branch isolate both?  Sounds like it makes a merge problem where one didn't exist before?

Comment: I was thinking of damage control. Can @User1 aver that there is a _de facto_ UI design and not just an (evolving) mockup?

Comment: I'm trying to eliminate merging conflicts. Having two separate java files would be ideal.

Answer (score 2):

I'd follow along with what Spring MVC does for web clients:

Inject the listeners into the Swing client, a la Spring dependency injection.  Have the UI developer simply call the listener instances without knowing what they're doing.

It'll let you keep all the logic for processing events in a class that's outside the Swing view classes.

You'll need to have a way to update the model inside the listeners and make it available to the Swing instances.

Version control is not your salvation; interfaces are.  Create interfaces to isolate the view code from the rest.  You can be independent as long as the interfaces don't change.

By interface, I mean Java interface:

```
public interface Foo {
    void doSomething(ModelObject m);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean something like [`Action`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html)?

Comment: Might be fine, but I meant injecting the Listeners that are usually associated with Swing Events - ActionListener, etc.  Those are - wait for it - interfaces.

Comment: OK, I'm on board with coding to the interface. Junior doesn't have to know that a particular `ActionListener` is actually an `Action`.

Comment: This sounds like a great idea, but much of the code in the listeners need to modify what is displayed on other controls.  For example, I click "next record", the next record in the database is loaded and the textboxes change to reflect the contents of the next record.  Is there a way to change the content of the textbox without having access to it?